# PHP8 Caching of recursive iterator?

Tags: php, php-8

I'm writing a PHP8 class that recursively searches a file directory for a given filename. However I need to search for 100's of files, I have recursive loop which works but I can only iterate 3 times before the maximum execution timeout occurs due to the large size of the folder which is the subject of the search.

My question is - can I just search the recursive directory once and cache it, either in a file or similar so that subsequent searches can be done on the cache?

What I have done so far:

```
$this->entries = $this->getEntries();
for($i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_rows($this->entries); $i++) {
     $data = mysqli_fetch_array($this->entries , MYSQLI_BOTH);
     foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($this->dir) as $filename => $file) {
          if(is_file($file)) {
               $filename = $file->getFilename();
               if ($filename == $data['name']) {
                   // do something
               }
           }
      }
 }
```

I guess I could copy the result of RescusiveIterator into a db and then search the relevant field for the match. Is that the most efficient way to achieve this goal?

Comment: More or less, yes. The database will allow you to create indexes for quick lookups. Other solutions will likely just be attempts at re-implementing this and other DB functionality.

Comment: You may also want to move the actual iteration/index operation to a cron or background process so that it is not subject to the execution timeouts of web requests.

Comment: if you worry about the filesystem query cost why not just flip the loops ? if you want actual list you have to pay this cost anyway. its way easier to cache the db results which you are matching against then the folder/files structure, because they are just one dimensional and also small memory-wise. that way the cost for filesystem queries is payed just once, not per each file. also cache could mean just keeping at memory, does not has to be fancy in simple cases.